# Шмакодявка этимология

Tags: этимология

Каково происхождение (этимология) слова шмакодявка?

Answer (score 3):

[Точное происхождение слова неизвестно. Существует несколько версий.](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1312556-shmakodjavka-kogo-tak-nazyvajut-i-pochemu.html)

> 1. Адаптация слова на идише "шмак" (ругательство) под уменьшительное значение по типу "козявка", "малявка".
>
> Слово "шмак" (шмок, шмук) на идише означает: 1) идиот (дурак по своей
>   оплошности) 2) мужской половой член, 3) мужчина (иронично).
>
> 2. От слов смак и дiвка (девка).

Варианты процитированного см. 
[Каково происхождение слова ШМАКОДЯВКА?](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/61131521)

См. также:
[Шмакодявка: Малолетка (обычно о девчонке).](http://slovoborg.su/definition/%D1%88%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0)

> Скорее всего, это слово имеет еврейско-русские корни и произошло от
>   двух слов: шмак - "вкусно" на идиш и "давить", т. е. поедать. Смысл:
>   малолетка, поглотитель и любитель вкусностей. Так как этим словом
>   называют малолетку, то слово "давить" искажено, так говорят эти самые
>   малолетки: не "давка", а "дявка". Так могли называть как девочку, так
>   и мальчика. Короче, *эй, шмакодявка, хочешь конфетку? Шмакодявка, не
>   мешай, не путайся под ногами!* Слово используется: Юг Украины, юг
>   России. Синонимы: малолетний, малолетка, мелюзга.
>
> ---
>
> Первая часть слова происходит от слова "шмок", одного из обозначений
>   на иврите мужского члена. Только в отличие от слов поц на иврите, либо
>   Potz на немецком, обозначающих непосредственно член, шмок - это
>   крайняя плоть, которая действительно делает "шмяк" (падает) при
>   обрезании. Соответственно "чмок" - это поцелуй головки полового члена,
>   а "чмо" - то, как уголовники относятся к мужчине так поступающему. А
>   что до смака, то конечно, форшмак, еврейское блюдо из рыбы переводится
>   дословно - для смака.
>
> ---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

"шмакодявка" состоит из двух слов:

1. "шмак" на иврите означает мyдак
2. "козявка" по отношению к человеку означает маленький или некто низкого роста.

Т.е. в общем "шмакодявка" означает "маленький Мудачок"

Comment: Что Ваш ответ добавляет к уже данному ответу?